# Mental block playing rolling chords

Tags: piano, chords

I am playing a piece in Grade 6 which starts with a rolling chord in left hand.  For some reason I find it really difficult to start and my little finger bounces up and down without being able to start the chord.  It seems to be a mental block. Can anyone help with breaking this?

Comment: A pic of the dots would help, or even saying what the notes are. Does it start on a black or a white key? Even this will have a bearing on helping.

Comment: If you can play arpeggios, you can play rolled chords - just "forget" to take your fingers off each note after you play it!

Answer (score 1):

The longest journey starts with the first step.  Just place your hand in the right position for rolling the chord and play only the first note and imagine the rest of the rolled chord only.  Only once you are satisfied with this first note as the beginning of the rolled chord, start actually adding the rest.

Rolling a chord in the right hand makes the little finger come last which just makes it fall into place.  The little finger is weakest and shares a sinew sheath with the ring finger, so its movement is somewhat dependent on the next finger.

So when you start with the little finger, you are starting with the weakest finger.  Just practice it without the others at first, until you have confidence in its delivery.